# FusionChart StackedBar2D vertical Scrolling

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, fusioncharts

I am using Fusion Charts for creating graphs.
I am using StackedBar2D currently for displaying my data.
As my data increases, the graphs starts overlapping, and nothing is readable.
I am unable to find a way to incorporate x-axis scrolling, i.e., vertical scrolling.
Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vertical scrolling is not supported in the Stacked Bar chart as of now. However, you can skip labels using "labelStep" attribute to show every n-th label for better clarity and prevent overlapping.